# Iterar las keys de los objetos

Tags: javascript

La funcion recibe dos objetos "obj1" y "obj2". Retornar las keys de las propiedades que sean únicas en cada objeto.

Ej:

```
let obj1 = {nombre: "Luciano", apellido: "Nicolau"}
let obj2 = {nombre: "Lio", segundoNombre: "Gustavo"}
clavesUnicas(obj1, obj2) retorna => ["apellido", "segundoNombre"];
```

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo por tu cuenta?

Comment: Recuerda que **aquí no hacemos tareas**. ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué problemas tuviste? Lee [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te dejo un ejemplo sencillo de como usar el método [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) y de las [plantillas literales](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
const main = document.getElementById("main");
function getKeys(){
    const obj = [{name: "Juan", lastname: "Alberto"}, {name: "Pedro", lastname: "Damian"}, {name: "Luis", lastname: "Angel"}];
    obj.forEach((item) => {
        const template = `
            <span>${item.name}</span>
            <span>${item.lastname}</span><br />
        `;
    main.innerHTML += template;
    });
}

getKeys();
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div id ="main"></div>
  <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```